# CrossMediaManager throws AVAsset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler while playing mp3 remote files in Xamarin Forms IOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, plugin.media.crossmedia

I am trying to play a list of media items with CrossMediaManager. However, in IOS it throws a weired error and doesn't perform playing, while the same code works in Android. If I do pass a single string url or media item then it works, but it doesn't work with multiple urls.

```
    static async Task<MediaItem> GenerateReciterMediaItem(string fileUri, AudioReciter reciter, byte chapterId)
    {
         Chapter c = await Chapter.GetChapterAsync(chapterId);
         var item = (MediaItem)await CrossMediaManager.Current.Extractor.CreateMediaItem(fileUri);
         item.MediaType = MediaType.Audio;
         var reciterImageUri = Path.Combine("http://www.azee.tech/reciters/r9.png"); //doesn't work
         //another url for image reciter.azee.tech/r9.png --> also doesn't work
         var image = new Image() { Source = ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri(reciterImageUri))};
         int type = 1;
         if (item != null)
         {
            item.Id = string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", type, chapterId, reciter.ReciterID);
            item.IsMetadataExtracted = false;
            item.Title = reciter.Name;
            item.Album = string.Format("{0} - {1} ({2})", c.ChapterID, c.ArabicEnglishName, c.EnglishName);
            item.Artist = reciter.Name;
            item.AlbumImage = image;
            item.AlbumImageUri = reciterImageUri;
            item.DisplayImage = image;
            item.DisplayImageUri = reciterImageUri;
            item.Image = image;
            item.ImageUri = reciterImageUri;
         }
     return item;
 }

static async Task AddAudioReciterTrackToQueue()
{
  //list of urls --> https://www.azee.tech/MaherAlMuaiqly64kbps/001.mp3 , 002.mp3, 003.mp3 and so on
  foreach(var url in listOfUrls)
  {
      var fileUri = listOfUrls[i];
      var item = await GenerateReciterMediaItem(fileUri, type, reciter, chapterId);
      CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.Add(item);
   }
}
async Task PlayQueue()
{
    CrossMediaManager.Current.AutoPlay = true;
    await AddAudioReciterTrackToQueue();
    
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(CrossMediaManager.Current.Queue.MediaItems); //doesnt work
    await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(); //doesn't work
}
```

Error from debug

> 2020-09-15 22:31:43.550896+0100 wQuran.iOS[29476:23403374] -[AVAsset
> loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:] invoked with
> unrecognized keys (
> albumName,
> author,
> title,
> artist ). [0:] state changed Buffering Thread started:  #22 2020-09-15 22:31:43.758802+0100 wQuran.iOS[29476:23404151] -[AVAsset
> loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:completionHandler:] invoked with
> unrecognized keys (
> artwork ).

If I download the file and play it from Local resource. No error.
I have also added Transport Security in info.plist to ignore https from this domain

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
    <key>www.azee.tech</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
      <false/>
      <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Can you check if the items have been download successfully and added to the queue successfully?

Comment: @ARH were you able to figure this out? I am playing files that are stored in the App Cache and get the same messages, although they don't hinder playback, would like to figure out how to get rid of them.

Comment: I solved the issue, but I couldn't add them like a list as in the code. I used to play one media and only one media was in the list. However, if you are trying to play a list, I suggest to pass an array of songs not the way in the code.